# Datatable heading alignment adjustments

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am using datatable in a modal popup. When I open the popup on button click then the heading i.e. theads of the table is not adjusting itself to the full width of the table. And below are the two scenarios in which theads adjust themselves accordingly.

1- open popup, thead are misaligned, then just open chrome developer tools and close them, now theads are aligned automatically. See image one

2- open popup while chrome developer tools are also open, now theads are not aligned correctly, now just resize the window from top right corner and BOOM the theads are aligned perfectly. See image two

can anybody tell me whats happening here. I am also attaching the images and code below.

```
 var table = $('#available-linguists').DataTable( {
      "dom": '<fl<t>ip>',
      "paging": false,
      "bInfo" : false,
      "scrollY": "250px",
      "scrollCollapse": true,
 });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering [`columns.adjust()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) when you show your modal:

```
table.columns.adjust();
```

> This method is provided to have DataTables recalculate the columns sizes, based on the data in the table and the size applied to the columns (in the DOM, CSS or through the columns.width parameter). **Call it when the table becomes visible if hidden when initialised (for example in a tab) or when the data changes significantly.**

Also note, the reason the columns magically align themselves when you resize the window is also mentioned in those same docs:

> DataTables will automatically call this method on the window resize event to keep the columns in sync with the re-flowed layout.

Comment: You have to trigger it *when you show your modal*.  Are you doing that?

Comment: It would be easier to give more specific guidance if you include what kind of model you are using, as well as relevant javascript  in your question.